# How to install previous version of GitKraken in Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, git

recently GitKraken has become non-free and I don't have the money to pay it , so I thought that I could try to return to an older version where GitKraken was free , but I don't know if actually I can do that in Ubuntu.

Comment: Unless GitKraken has distributed a free version of their app which doesn't auto-update, somewhere that you can download and use it, I'd say it's very unlikely, and this isn't related to Ubuntu really. Also, this is tagged with `14.04` which is no longer supported by the community, so I'd strongly suggest upgrading your Ubuntu version if you are indeed running that.